# How can I write a unit test for a Docker container with Flask web service?

Tags: python, docker, flask, tox

I have a Flask web service inside a Docker container.

What I currently do:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm my_image serve.py
$ curl -d '{"foo": "bar", "foo2": "bar2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v http://localhost:8080/ping
```

If that returns status code 200, it's fine.

Can I do this automatically? Preferably with `tox`?

Answer (score 1):

[Docker HealthChecks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) might useful. A health check is a command that is executed regularly to determine if a container is healthy.

Health checks usually consist of curling an http endpoint and checking the return code.

You can define a health check inside the Dockerfile as such:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
 CMD curl -d '{"foo": "bar", "foo2": "bar2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v http://localhost:8080/ping || exit 1
```

Or when running the container as such:

```
docker run --health-cmd='curl -d '{"foo": "bar", "foo2": "bar2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v http://localhost:8080/ping || exit 1' --health-interval=5m  --health-timeout=3s ...
```

The container health will then show next to the status when running `docker container ls`